# Making a task every x time

Tags: java

I use the attached code to send to my db every 5 min some information, some of the information  is timestamp.
When I look in my db I see records with 6 minute diffrence and even 7, how come? Some told me that my task takes too long.

Anyway my question is how I can force my code to send the info the to the db every 5 min.

*Important thing I have to say that I have a condition on the task which means that sometimes it won't do a thing so the diffrence between the records should be multiples of five.

```
this.timer.schedule(new Send(), new Date(), TEN_SECONDS*6*5);

class Send extends TimerTask
{
    public void run()
    {
        if(location!=null)
        {
            if (mGeocoderAvailable) 
                address = reverseGeocode(LocationService.this.location);
            if(address != "" && !address.equals(lastAddress))
            {
                lastAddress = address;
                new SendLocation(LocationService.this.id,address);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The SendLocation body is like this:

```
public SendLocation(int id,String address)
{
    // taking care the parameters
    this.start();
}
public void run() 
{ 
    //connect to db
    //send location to db
    this.destroy();
}
```

Comment: How about writing the current time to System.out as the first thing you do in the run method?  That would tell if the task is firing every five minutes.  In fact, you probably want to sprinkle these statements throughout your code so that you can tell what is happening and when.

Comment: You could also consider using a http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html.

Comment: @EJK thank you, looks like my problem was that the time was scheduled inside the SendLocation class instead of inside the Send class.

Answer (score 0):

The time was scheduled inside the SendLocation thread instead from the Send task.